# JavaScript format input values to float

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects, dom-events

I want to convert different input values to a float no matter pretty much the format in which they are input.

For example, these values:

```
€ 1500000
€ 1.500.000
1500000
1.500.000
```

Should all convert to a float type with two decimals, e.g. `1500000.00`

While I'm able to strip the euro symbol successfully and also strip white space I'm not able to convert `1.500.000` to `1500000.00`.

This is what I have so far:

```
var propertyValue2 = $scope.Data.PropertyCost.match(numberPattern);
propertyValue2 = $.trim($scope.Data.PropertyCost).replace(/€/g, '');
propertyValue2 = parseFloat(propertyValue2);
propertyValue2 = propertyValue2.toFixed(2);
console.log(propertyValue2);
```

How can I achieve the result I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression to match only digits:

```js
var test = [
  '€ 1500000',
  '€ 1.500.000',
  '1500000',
  '1.500.000'
]
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  console.log(
    test[i],
    'evaluate to',
    parseFloat(test[i].toString().replace(/\D/g, '')).toFixed(2)
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I you do not have the dot as decimal separator, you could change the regular expression a bit.

```js
var propertyValue2 = '€ 12.000.123';
propertyValue2 = propertyValue2.trim().replace(/[€.]/g, '');
propertyValue2 = +propertyValue2;
propertyValue2 = propertyValue2.toFixed(2);
console.log(propertyValue2);
```